# How to run application with elevated permissions in AutoLISP or ObjectARX

Tags: autocad, autocad-plugin, autolisp, objectarx

I need to run the application which requires elevated permissions in AutoCAD/ZWCAD.

By LISP I can run the application using:

```
(startapp "C:\\[path]\\Application.exe")
```

But for application requiring elevater permisions `startapp` returns `nil` and application not runs.

Tried also:

```
(setq Shell (vlax-get-or-create-object "Wscript.Shell"))
(setq updater(vlax-invoke-method Shell 'Exec (strcat path "Appname.exe" ) ) )
(vlax-release-object Shell)
```

but I got:

```
*error*: Automation error : WshShell.Exec : The requested operation requires elevation.
```

So is any other way to run external application requiring elevated permisions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that it can be done in both, LISP and C++ ObjectARX so:

**LISP:**

```
(startapp "C:\\[path]\\run.bat")
```

and in the run.bat

```
CALL "C:\[path]\Application.exe"
```

works OK on my site

**ObjectARX C++**

```
CString AppPath = _T("C:\\[path]\\");
CString App = AppPath + _T("Application.exe");
HINSTANCE aplication = ShellExecute(0, _T("open") , App , NULL , AppPath , SW_SHOWNORMAL);
```

Answer (score 0):

May be you can try `RunAs`?

```
(startapp "runas /user:administrator C:\\[path]\\Application.exe")
```

Of course, you will be prompted for password.

You can find alternatives here: https://superuser.com/q/55809/60438

Comment: I want to avoid prompting for password